# Options for running on user demand asynchronous / background tasks in Django?

Tags: django

My Django app generates a complex report that can take upto 5 minutes to create. Therefore it runs once a night using a scheduled management command.

That's been ok, except I now want the user to be able to select the date range for the report, which means the report needs to be created while the user waits.

What are my options for running the tast in the background? So far I've found these:

- Celery - might work but is complex
- django-background-tasks looks like the right tool for the job but hasn't been updated for years, last supported Django is 2.2
- The report/background task could be generated by AWS Lambda, basically in a microservice. Django calls the Microservice which can execute the background task then call the Django app back once finished. This is what I did last time but not sure it would work now as I'd need to send the microservice 10mb of data to process.
- Use subprocess.popen which someone here said worked for them but other reports say it doesn't work from Django.

EDIT: Looks like Django 3.1 onwards supports ASync views and may be the simple solution for this.

Comment: Looks like a classic use of Celery. What is the problem ?

Comment: Hi JT, I have read through a couple of Celery tutorials, it certainly doesn't seem like a simple lightweight solution, but happy to revisit this option. I just noticed there's now async views in Django 3.1.